# FontLab Glyph Name to Unicode Mapping Not Working

Tags: unicode, fonts, font-face, webfonts, truetype

I have created my own font pack with a custom encoding file which worked great. I am just having trouble using the "Generate Unicodes" feature. I want the Glyphs to automatically take on corresponding unicodes based on the mapping file.

I created a file called standard.nam and place it in "FontLab VI.app/Contents/Resources" as suggested. I even created a custom file and pointed the app to it.

No matter what I do the Glyph names never match to their corresponding Unicodes. Nothing happens at all when I click the little refresh unicode name.

How do I get this to work? I want my Glyph using my custom encoding file to get assigned their unicodes from the ".nam" database file. Below is my current file:

```
%FONTLAB NAMETABLE[: Database_name]
0x0020 !visiblespace
0x0020 space
0x0021 exclam
0x0022 quotedbl
0x0023 numbersign
0x0024 dollar
```

HELP PLEASE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Fontlab team I was able to fix it. The updated code is below and I hope it helps someone else:

```
%%FONTLAB NAMETABLE: Database Name
0x0020 !visiblespace
0x0020 space
0x0021 exclam
0x0022 quotedbl
0x0023 numbersign
0x0024 dollar
```